# AEM Touch UI radio button does not readback values stored in the node

Tags: aem

I'm trying to add a radio button to a dialog (Granite/Coral UI). The button can store values in the node. But when the dialog is opened again it does not get initialized with the values stored.I also have a classic UI Dialog. When values are edited through it and the dialog is reopened it get's initialized. When values are edited through the touch UI , the dialog is classic UI does not read values stored in the node. I have a textfield in the dialog and it works fine irrespective of the UI used.

The names used in both dialogs are the same.

JSON of the Touch UI nodes :

`{

      "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
      "jcr:title":"Field Set Title as Field label for button group",
      "sling:resourceType":"granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset",
      "items":{

        "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
        "charset":{

          "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
          "name":"_charset_",
          "value":"utf-8",
          "ignoreData":true,
          "sling:resourceType":"granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
        },
        "Button1":{

          "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
          "name":"./radioButton",
          "text":"button 1",
          "value":"button 1",
          "checked":true,
          "sling:resourceType":"granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio"
        },
        "Button2":{

          "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
          "name":"./radioButton",
          "text":"button 2",
          "value":"button 2",
          "sling:resourceType":"granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio"
        }
      }
   }`

JSON for Classic UI :

`{

  "jcr:primaryType":"cq:Panel",
  "title":"Tab 1",
  "items":{

    "jcr:primaryType":"cq:WidgetCollection",
    "sampleText":{

      "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
      "name":"./sampleText",
      "xtype":"textfield",
      "fieldLabel":"sample text"
    },
    "radioButton":{

      "jcr:primaryType":"cq:Widget",
      "name":"./radioButton",
      "type":"radio",
      "xtype":"selection",
      "fieldLabel":"Radio Button",
      "options":{

        "jcr:primaryType":"cq:WidgetCollection",
        "button 1":{

          "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
          "text":"Button 1",
          "value":"Button 1"
        },
        "button 2":{

          "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
          "text":"Button 2",
          "value":"Button 2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Sharath, is this the same issue that I reported earlier and you tried it from your end?

Comment: @SharathMadappa : Hi did you found the solution for this, If yes then please post as answer.

Comment: @VDhim : Hi haven't found the solution yet. Let me know if you find.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your radio fields inside a radioGroup. The resource type is 'granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radiogroup'.

example:

```
+ myradiogroup
    - sling:resourceType = "granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radiogroup"
    + items
      + option1
        - sling:resourceType = "granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio"
        - name = "browser"
        - value = "ie"
        - text = "Internet Explorer"
      + option2
        - sling:resourceType = "granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio"
        - name = "browser"
        - value = "chrome"
        - text = "Chrome"
      + option3
        - sling:resourceType = "granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio"
        - name = "browser"
        - value = "firefox"
        - text = "Firefox"
```